# Check the Status of Emails Sent by Postfix

Tags: email, smtp, postfix-mta

I'm writing an application that sends emails using postfix and need to know an email is sent (250 ok) or not. I can check the email status from log files (and parse it by something like rsyslog) , but it's not a clean way.
My question is : **is there any clean way (Api or callback) to check the status of an email?**

Thank you.